# Is there a way to set the .skinActive(“#fefa01”) property for the iOS player (JWplayer)

Tags: ios, jwplayer

Is there a way to set the .**skinActive**(“#fefa01”) property for the iOS player (JWplayer / JWConfig class) ?

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406968-using-jw-player-skins

**skin.active**
Active skin elements. This includes active and highlighted labels, as well scrubber time that has elapsed .

**skin.inactive**
Skin elements that are not active. This includes scrubber time that has not yet elapsed.

**skin.background**
The background portion of the control bar.

// iOS Config

```
// basic config
JWConfig *config = [JWConfig new];    
config.image = nil;
config.title = @" ";
config.controls = YES;  //default
config.repeat = NO;   //default
config.offlineMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"connection.title", nil);
//config.premiumSkin = JWPremiumSkinSeven;

//custom skin can be applied using:
config.cssSkin = @"http://urltomycustomcssfile.css";
```

Or is it possible to workaround this by overwriting the proper css styles using **config.cssSkin** ? I tried but I don't know which styles to overwrite and if this works as well.

i.e.

```
.jw-skin-seven .jw-progress {
    background: #fefa01;
}
```

Comment: You should also post your question on the JW support forum

Comment: @JessevanMuijden - done .. https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16101445-is-there-a-way-to-set-active-skin-elements-ios-sdk-?new=16101445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do that on the iOS SDK. JWplayer will create a feature request for a future release.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16101445-is-there-a-way-to-set-active-skin-elements-ios-sdk-?new=16101445